# How to access Rest APIs mentioned in Controller class of a Jar file in my Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring / Spring Boot.

In my Spring Boot Application, I have a **JAR** file which has a Controller class and corresponding Service Interface (not class). I have implemented the Service interface and created a Service class with some logic. Now I want to access the APIs (/v1/getDetails) present in Controller class of JAR file.

Can we access the REST APIs present in Controller class of JAR file? If so then please guide me.

PS: I have tried to search on internet but didn't get a clear answer.

**Controller class in Jar:**

```java
    @RestController("/v1")  
    public class BasicRestController {  
        @Autowired  
        BasicServiceInterface basicService;  

        @GetMapping("/supportedDeviceTypes")
        public NameValuePair<?> getSupportedDeviceTypes() {
            return basicService.getSupportedDeviceTypes();
        }
    }
```

**Spring Boot Main Class:**

```java
    @SpringBootApplication  
    public class XXXProjectApplication{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(XXXProjectApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**Configuration Class:**

```java
    @Configuration  
    public class CommonControllerConfig {  

        @Bean
        public BasicRestController basicRestController() {
            return new BasicRestController();
        }
    }
```

Accessing http://localhost:8080/v1/supportedDeviceTypes but getting - 'This application has no explicit mapping..' in browser.

But I have printed the loaded beans in Application Context and could see BasicRestController bean is loaded while starting the app.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Is the jar included in another web application? If yes, have you tried including the controller as a bean in the web app?

Comment: @Smile Yes, the jar is included in another Spring BOOT Application which I have run and trying to access the API present in the jar.

Comment: So, access it. What happens when you do it? As long as the controller is a Spring bean registered (scanned, typically) in the Boot application, it doesn't matter whether it's in a jar or in another jar.

Comment: Then, make sure the controller class is configured as bean. for eg. `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.controller.package")` is added to spring boot config. It will help if you edit your question and add code of controller as well as spring boot main class.

Comment: @Smile I have added the Controller as well as Spring Boot main class please check.

Comment: Accessing http://localhost:8080/v1/supportedDeviceTypes but getting - 'This application has no explicit mapping..' in browser.

But I have printed the loaded beans in Application Context and could see BasicRestController bean is loaded while starting the app.

Comment: It should be `@RestController @RequestMapping("/v1")`. In your code, `/v1`is the name of the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing following bean from `CommonControllerConfig`

```java
        @Bean
        public BasicRestController basicRestController() {
            return new BasicRestController();
        }
```

And instead add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.controller.package")`
Also, as JB Nizet mentioned, it should be `@RestController @RequestMapping("/v1")` in `BasicRestController`.

Comment: Adding ComponentScan instead of Bean solved the problem. I think Bean only scans one particular class of the jar file in my case, not all the class files of jar.

"Also, as JB Nizet mentioned, it should be @RestController @RequestMapping("/v1") in BasicRestController." - yes that's correct.

After modifying as per the suggestions my code worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Hi @Surya, how did you solve this? I have same problem and I don’t know of any solution to solve this. Here is my query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461051/accessing-intellij-gradle-based-spring-boot-service-application-jar-file-throw